# Jetpack Compose WebView PDF Printing Adds Padding (White Spaces) to Border

Tags: android, html, kotlin, webview, android-jetpack-compose

I am working on an Android app using Jetpack Compose, and I have a WebView in which I display HTML content. I want to provide users with the ability to download the WebView's content as a PDF. For this purpose, I'm using the getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE) method along with createPrintDocumentAdapter() to generate the PDF.

However, when I download the WebView content as a PDF, I notice that it adds padding (white spaces) to the border, which negatively affects the overall appearance of the PDF. I have tried using PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS, but it doesn't seem to solve the issue.
Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
fun printWebPage(webView: WebView?, originalContext: Context) {
    if (webView != null) {
        val printManager = originalContext.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE) as PrintManager
        val jobName = "webpage_" + System.currentTimeMillis()

        val printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter(jobName)

        // Define the printing attributes
        val printAttributes = PrintAttributes.Builder()
            .setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4)
            .setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS)
            .build()

        // Start the printing process
        printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter, printAttributes)
    }
}
```

[image: this is a screenshoot]